# Trackpad recognized as a mouse, gestures not working. Ubuntu 15.10 on Asus F55UJ-XX006T

Tags: 15.10, mouse, touchpad, asus, multi-touch

I have a strange problem with my notebook: Ubuntu recognizes the touchpad as a mouse and I can't use the double finger scrolling. When I open "mouse settings" here's what appears:

[image]

I found only solutions for older Ubuntu versions.

EDIT:

```
xxxx@yyyy:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but I was busy these days. I added the info you required

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`? If it is 4.2, then this touchpad is not supported in Ubuntu 15.10. It is supported in Ubuntu 14.04 with `xenial` kernel or Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: 4.2.0-34-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 10 22:13:01 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This touchpad should work on Ubuntu 14.04 after you install 4.4 kernel by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

or in Ubuntu 16.04 out of the box.

This touchpad is not supported by Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-xenial

Comment: Do you run it on 14.04?

Comment: sorry, I didn't run it on 14.04. I will wait for the 16.04 release. Thank you for the answer :)